# Cannot open dump wallet file (code-8)

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, electrum, full-node

Is anybody familiar with this problem using btc qt debug console?

Would like to dump wallet and sweep into electrum.

Comment: What is the exact command you're using?

Comment: Dumpwallet. To a created txt file on my C drive. Don't know what the problem is. What does code -8 mean? Should I use a certain type of txt file? Should I stop syncing my node while doing it? Any help would be great.

Comment: Well you need to pass the file name to dump to, how are you soecifying that?

Comment: In the debug console i type Dumpwallet C:\...\...

Comment: Should I stop syncing? I'm getting a new error now. No longer "code-8"

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the filename in quotes.

eg:

```
dumpwallet "C:\output.txt"
```

As opposed to:

```
dumpwallet C:\output.txt      (wrong)
```